# Square-list "Compare Constructor" Implementation

Tags: c++, boost, constructor

For a homework assignment, I've to implement a square-list (already done) and pass all the unit tests provided. I've passed all but one and this specific unit test tests for the implementation of a "compare constructor."

Here are the boost unit tests involved:

```
#include "ut_square_list.hpp"
#include <boost\test\auto_unit_test.hpp>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

template <class T>
class RuntimeCmp
{
public:
    enum cmp_mode { normal, reverse };
private:
    cmp_mode mode;
public:
    RuntimeCmp( cmp_mode m = normal ) : mode(m) { } // constructor
    bool operator()(T const& t1, T const& t2) const { return mode == normal ? t1 < t2 : t2 < t1; } // function call operator - 
    bool operator==( RuntimeCmp const& rc ) { return mode == rc.mode; }
};



/** Test square_list<T>::square_list() */
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ut_ctor_compare_def ) {
    square_list<double,RuntimeCmp<double>> s;
    vector<double> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for (auto x : data)
        s.insert(x);

    BOOST_CHECK( std::equal( s.begin(), s.end(), data.begin() ) );
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ut_ctor_compare_passed ) {
    RuntimeCmp<double> rc(RuntimeCmp<double>::reverse);
    square_list<double,RuntimeCmp<double>> s(rc);
    vector<double> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };


    for (auto x : data)
        s.insert(x);

    BOOST_CHECK( std::equal( s.begin(), s.end(), data.rbegin() ) );
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ut_ctor_compare_iterator_passed ) {
    vector<double> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    RuntimeCmp<double> rc(RuntimeCmp<double>::reverse);
    square_list<double,RuntimeCmp<double>> s(data.begin(),data.end(),rc);

    BOOST_CHECK( std::equal( s.begin(), s.end(), data.rbegin() ) );
}
```

What is a "compare constructor" based on the above? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the context you have given I think "compare constructor" refers to a constructor that takes a compare object as a parameter.

While terms like "default constructor" or "copy constructor" are language specific, "compare constructor" is not. It is specific for this homework assignment.

Comment: What about this line:

  BOOST_CHECK( std::equal( s.begin(), s.end(), data.rbegin() ) );

How does that make sense?

Comment: @Bojs Ask what it means. It means that the order of `s` is reversed when `s` is initialized with a `RuntimeCmp<T>` instance with mode `reverse`.